# Order results based on ordering of IDS passed to IN

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Given

```
ids = [4, 2, 1, 3]
dishes = Dish.where("restaurant_id in (?)", ids)
```

Would it be possible to sort dishes based on the sequence of ids?

```
=> # I'd like to see something like this
=> dishes.map(&:restaurant_id)
=> [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3] etc.

I'm currently getting something like this
=> [1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4]
```

I know that I could either loop through ids and then just `select` the dishes that match the given id then rebuild the array but I can't do that since I'd still like to use `will_paginate` on the association.

Any help or tip would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And how are results sorted now?

Comment: Sergio Let me edit. abjihit that wont work since restaurant_id has its own sequence.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand your question, i thot it was plain: Dishes.where("restaurant_id in (?)", ids).order("restaurant_id desc").map{|j| j.restaurant_id}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only efficient (by which I mean "push it to the database") thing I can think of here is to build a custom order by clause for the database by iterating through the array of restaurant ids to generate text such as:

```
order by
  case restaurant_id
    when 4 then 1
    when 2 then 2
    when 1 then 3
    when 3 then 4
  end
```

Hopefully that pattern is enough for you to infer the logic for building such a string.

The activerecord call should look something like:

```
dishes = Dish.where("restaurant_id in (?)", ids).
              order("case restaurant_id when 4 then 1 when 2 then 2 when 1 then 3 when 3 then 4 end")
```

Comment: That works but it's returning an array! I badly need an ActiveRecord::Relation :-(. Ideas?

Comment: r = Dish.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM dishes WHERE restaurant_id in (4, 2, 1, 3) ORDER BY case restaurant_id when 4 then 1 when 2 then 2 when 1 then 3 when 3 then 4 end")

Comment: Your code works as is, it sorts it properly but it returns an array :-(.

Comment: Ah, don't use find_by_sql, just specify the string in the order clause. I'll mod the answer ...

Comment: That works, thank you so much, you just saved me a sleepless night!